# "kde-config not found" error while installing kstars from source

Tags: compiling

I am trying to install kstars from source ,but I got the following error while configuring

```
./configure
checking build system type... i686-pc-linux-gnu
checking host system type... i686-pc-linux-gnu
checking target system type... i686-pc-linux-gnu
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking for -p flag to install... yes
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... mawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking for kde-config... not found
configure: error: The important program kde-config was not found!
Please check whether you installed KDE correctly.
```

What does it mean ,I already installed kde in my computer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looks like you're missing `kdelibs5-dev`:

```
sudo apt-get install kdelibs5-dev
```

You can make sure all the build dependencies of kstars is installed by installing its build dependencies:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep kstars
```

Comment: kdelibs5-dev doesn't contains kde-config.

Answer (score 14):

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/kde4-config /usr/bin/kde-config
```

Comment: this is actually essential step for it to work since -dev package provides kde4-config +1 this

Comment: What if I don't have sudo permissions. Can I pass the kde4-config as some PREFIX for configure?