# 20.04 Configure Error: The important program KDE-Config was not found

Tags: 20.04, package-management, kde

I have a package that I'm trying to configure from source on Ubuntu 20.04 in order to install it, However Configure fails with the following error:

```
Configure: Checking for KDE-Config … Not found
Configure: Error: The important program KDE-Config was not found
```

I Have KDE5 installed and tried to lookup the package online and didn't find it

can anybody tell me what package provides "KDE-Config" on Ubuntu 20.04??

Comment: `/usr/bin/kde-config` : "KDE 3" . Other kdeX-config  https://askubuntu.com/questions/136655/kde-config-not-found-error-while-installing-kstars-from-source .............  Which application are you trying to build ? ?

Comment: What is Configure? From where you got it?

Comment: @KnudLarsen I'm trying to install KNDISWrapper, not sure if you've heard of it

Comment: @N0rbert It's a way of installation for some packages

Comment: KNDISWrapper, latest is https://github.com/maz-1/kndiswrapper .... also for `qt5` . ........ (You probably got the year 2008 version.)

Answer (score 1):

NDISWrapper by itself is available in [official Ubuntu repositories](https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/focal-updates/ndiswrapper). To install it use commands below:

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ndiswrapper # ndiswrapper-dkms
```

Then about KNDISWrapper KDE front-end.
It is [available](https://repology.org/projects/?search=kndiswrapper&maintainer=&category=&inrepo=&notinrepo=&repos=&families=&repos_newest=&families_newest=) [only on ArchLinux](https://repology.org/project/kndiswrapper-qt5/versions). The relevant package was last updated [in 2015-2017](https://aur.archlinux.org/cgit/aur.git/tree/PKGBUILD?h=kndiswrapper-qt5). To compile it on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (focal fossa) use commands below:

```
sudo apt-get install git build-essential qt5-default qttools5-dev-tools

cd ~/Downloads
git clone https://github.com/maz-1/kndiswrapper.git
cd kndiswrapper/
mkdir -p build
cd build
qmake ..
make
cd ..
cp -r translations ./build/
lrelease ./build/translations/*.ts

sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/share/{kndiswrapper,applications,pixmaps}
sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/bin

sudo cp "./icons/kndiswrapper.svg" "/usr/local/share/kndiswrapper/kndiswrapper.svg"
sudo cp "./icons/kndiswrapper.svg" "/usr/local/share/pixmaps/kndiswrapper.svg"
sudo cp build/kndiswrapper /usr/local/bin
sudo chmod 755 "/usr/local/bin/kndiswrapper"
sudo cp "./build/translations/"*.qm "/usr/local/share/kndiswrapper"
sudo cp "./build/translations/cards_known_to_work.txt" "/usr/local/share/kndiswrapper"
```

and finally create desktop-icon file for it using long single command below

```
cat <<EOF | sudo tee "/usr/local/share/applications/kndiswrapper.desktop"
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=kndiswrapper
Name[de]=kndiswrapper
GenericName=kndiswrapper
GenericName[de]=kndiswrapper
Comment=A GUI for ndiswrapper
Comment[de]=Eine GUI fuer ndiswrapper.
Exec=kndiswrapper
Icon=kndiswrapper
Terminal=false
Type=Application
StartupNotify=true
Categories=Network;
EOF
```

and then find icon in applications menu/dash.